# Admob Banner doesn't show

Tags: ios, admob

I want to implement Admob into an app for iPad in landscape mode, I followed step by step tutorial for admob, on adding advertising to the app. I added all the frameworks and requirements given to work correctly.

I can't see the banner. I tried both the simulator and on the device itself. According to the following [link](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/best-practices) it seems that:

"Test ads are not supported on iOS 6 devices; use the simulator instead"

The compilation is correct without issues.
I changed the background of the red banner, and I moved all the views that would hide the banner, but still I couldn't see it. Inside the viewDidLoad method, I have placed it in different positions

From Google admob statistics I see that increase requests, this I don't understand. O___O

The AdMob SDK is the latest.

I appreciate any help.

My code:

```
bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc]
initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,
                         self.view.frame.size.height -
                         GAD_SIZE_728x90.height,
                         GAD_SIZE_728x90.width,
                         GAD_SIZE_728x90.height)];

bannerView_.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;
bannerView_.delegate = self; 

bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:bannerView_];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:bannerView_];

bannerView_.backgroundColor= [UIColor redColor];

GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       @"6A1E19F-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxDF38593ECBD" ,
                       @"9bc75xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx762de7c79fb", 
                       nil];
request.testing = YES;
[bannerView_ loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: hi, did u solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this

request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:**@[@"GAD_SIMULATOR_ID"]**, nil];

[*yourbannerview* loadRequest:request];

and delete request.test, is disabled now :/